# Safari transform translate doesent work correctly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, safari

I have a slider with `transform: translateX(...) translateY(...) translateZ(...) rotateY(...)` dynamically changing with React.
In Chrome its working fine, but in Safari it seems like  start point of transformation shifted on some variable value.
In inspector it seems like no mistakes, all prefixes are present.

Do you have any ideas? I can send some screenshots or code chunks, if needed

UPDATE

https://gist.github.com/korgara/92f629d49ba7afd76f2b771cd6b6c8dc

UPDATE
here is the screenshots 
http://i89.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0511/0c/0290ec27bb1326f0dedda9a1a280260c.png

Comment: what error you are getting in safari ?

Comment: The `translateX(...)` is shifted for some unexpected value.
Please, read my question one more time.

Answer (score 0):

> Use **webkit** for Safari

```
.class{
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Please refer below to know which browser supports what and what prefix has to be added. http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: As a said before, I used all prefixes in my styles.
The transformation is working in Safari, but its working uncorrectly.

Comment: No, i can`t, because my project is not released yet.
But I can send you a screenshots and code.